# Search a pattern word from multiple files and concatenate whole lines in a new file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have several data files. For example

sales.txt (the original file has 13 columns)

> Date Unit $$ employee# abc def jkl mno pqr
> Dec1 10 500 2 1 2 3 4 5
> Dec2 12 450 3 6 7 8 9 10
> Dec3 13 550 3 11 12 13 14 15
> Dec4 15 600 3 16 17 18 19 20
> ...
> ...

supply.txt (original one has 3 columns)

> Date Unit cost source1 source2 
> Dec1 10 300 5 5 
> Dec2 12 350 5 7 
> Dec3 13 350 7 6 
> Dec4 15 400 6 9 
> ...
> ...

And I have 3 other files which have 2 columns in each. What I am trying to do is match the date in all these files and copy the lines in a single file. The code I am using for this is:

```
# count the number of rows in the file 
file="sales.txt"
N=$(awk -F, '{rows++} END{print rows}' $file)

for row in $(eval echo {2..$N})
do 
 pattern=$(awk -v r=$row 'FNR==r {print $1}' $file);
 paste <(awk -v line=$row 'FNR==line{print $0}' $file) 
   <(awk -v line=$row 'FNR==line{$1=""; print $0}' supply.txt)
   <(awk -v line=$row 'FNR==line{print $2}' otherfile1.txt)
   <(awk -v line=$row 'FNR==line{print $2}' otherfile2.txt)
   <(awk -v line=$row 'FNR==line{print $2}' otherfile3.txt) >> account.txt
done
```

It is working in copying and finding the lines but the format in the output file is something like this:

> Dec1 10 500 2 1 2 3 4 5 10 300 5 5
> 1   # comes from otherfile1
> 2   # comes from otherfile2
> 3   # comes from otherfile3
> Dec2 12 450 3 6 7 8 9 10 12 350 5 7 
> 4
> 5
> 6
> ...
> ...

I want them to be on the same line. I have tried many techniques found in this forum but none of them has worked for me. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while IFS=" " read DATE REMAINS
do
  paste \
    <(printf "%s %s" "${DATE}" "${REMAINS}") \
    <(awk '
        /^'"${DATE}"'/ {
          for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) {
            text=(text == "" ? "" : text " ") $i}
            }
        END {
          print text
          }
        ' supply.txt)
done < <(sed -n '2,$p' sales.txt)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.